# Angular 2 triggering ngOnChanges

Tags: angular

I have an input field in Child component. When on blur event occurs, the value of this input passes to AppComponent by eventEmmiter and set a new value to the Key property of AppComponent. Since Child component's Key input decorator bind to this property, I'm expecting that ngOnChanges hook will be triggered in Child component, and will set previous value and current value to paragraphs. But it's not working.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klhjdf?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed `child` tag too early:

```html
<child 
  [key]="key"> <-------------------------------- here
  (triggerInputChanges)="handleKey($event)"
</child>
```

it should be

```html
<child 
  [key]="key"
  (triggerInputChanges)="handleKey($event)">
                                          ^^^^
                                          here
</child>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjoesr?file=app/app.component.html)**